# Different number of posts loaded

Tags: php, wordpress

so, I have the following post loop for wordpress

```
if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
        $paged = get_query_var('paged');
    } elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) {
        $paged = get_query_var('page');
    } else {
        $paged = 1;
    }
    $args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'paged'=>$paged,
        'posts_per_page' => 7,  
        'orderby' => 'date',            
        'order' => 'DESC'
        );
```

As you can see, every page brings out 7 posts.

Is there a way to have 1 post in the second page and 7 posts after on?

For example,

```
Page 1 (initial load)= 7 posts
Page 2 = 1 post
Page 3 and on = 7 posts
```

Thanks

Comment: changing the post-per-page on the fly like that is going to make for complicated re-calculating. e.g. if you want page 2, and you change posts_per_page back to one, then you're going to end up viewing the 2nd post from the 1st page... but that being said, `$posts_per_page = ($paged == 2) ? 1 : 7;`

Comment: I see. I will give that a try and see if there is alternate route without getting too complicated. Thanks for the help thought! =)